# Combining multiple tables into one large table

Tags: sql-server-2012

I would like to combine multiple tables of the same format (columns) into one large table so that I can run queries on the union of all the data.

For example:

Table1:

```
Product       Spec
AProduct 1    ASpec 1
AProduct 2    ASpec 2
```

Table 2:

```
Product      Spec
BProdcut 1   BSpec 1
BProduct 2   BSpec 2
```

Table 3:

```
Product      Spec
CProduct 1   CSpec 1
CProduct 2   CSpec 2
```

Want a large table to show:

```
Product      Spec
AProduct 1   ASpec 1
AProduct 2   ASpec 2
BProdcut 1   BSpec 1
BProduct 2   BSpec 2
CProduct 1   CSpec 1
CProduct 2   CSpec 2
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? You tagged your question with two different RDBMSs. Please remove the irrelevant tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [union operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)

Sample for TSQL:

```
select * from (
select Product, Spec
from Table1
union
select Product, Spec
from Table2
union
select Product, Spec
from Table3 ) as large_table
```

Or create a view and query it as usual.
Use "union all" to combine all the rows, and "union" to combine only unique rows (i.e. duplicates will be removed from the result set).

Comment: In your answer you should point out the difference between UNION and UNION ALL just to be complete

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Table

```
CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE table1;
```

Insert date from table 1 to 3

```
INSERT INTO newtable SELECT * FROM table1;
INSERT INTO newtable SELECT * FROM table2;
INSERT INTO newtable SELECT * FROM table3;
```

Now you can use the newtable